# Conditional formatting help required for Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to use conditional formatting to highlight when a provider has invoiced twice for the same session.

I can highlight duplicate reference numbers easily using this formula:

```
=COUNTIF($C$2:$C,C2)>1
```

So for example, provider NH has invoiced twice for the session on the `18/11/22` for reference `3445`, so I would like `J7` and `D17` to turn red.

I tried this formula after `#marikamitsos` helped me with a similar question earlier:

```
=INDEX((COUNTIF($C$2:$C&$D$2:$J,C2&D2:J2)>1)*(D2:J<>""))
```

but it’s not quite working and I can’t see what I’m missing?

> [example spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MT1F.jpg)

Comment: The image that you displayed is useful for understanding your scenario. But you should not expect users to re-create your data. Please Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide a link to a sample spreadsheet or post a table with sample data in the question. As mentioned by @Tedinoz we can not recreate your data so it would be better to work with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, I provided both a link to a sample spreadsheet, and what I believe is an mpe, so I'm not sure why they're not showing up (I am a novice, and this is only my second question, so apologies if I'm being thick) Thank you anyway for trying to help.

Comment: You could try pasting the link here in the comments or edit the question.